# How to clear the app cache and properly reload a web app (android, cordova)?

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications, html5-appcache

I am writing a web app that runs on android and uses apache cordova (phonegap). Occasionally the app receives info that a new version of the app is available. The procedure upon this information is to alert the user and at some point try to reload the app. I tried to use available html5 technologies to do this but it does not work properly on android (2.3 and higher). Then I decided to write a plugin for android to remedy the problem. But alas the solution is not so simple. I tried to manually clear the cache and reload but that does not work as expected. Here is the code for the plugin:

```
    public boolean execute(final String action, final JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (RELOAD.equals(action)) {
        try {
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        webView.clearCache(true);
                        webView.reload();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);
                    }
                }
            });

            final PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}}
```

I used runOnUiThread because I saw that it is used that way in the App plugin (cordova 2.4). I expected that when the code is run it would first clear the app cache and then the reload would load the new version. What happens is that upon reload the old version seems to be somewhere in memory and is loaded (I have an initial screen that shows the version). This continues for some time and at some point the webview figures out that there is a new version (the manifest is of course modified) and then starts loading the new version (again showing the initial screen). But to the user this looks like the app reloaded twice and I'd like to avoid that. How could that be achieved? Is there anything I can put in the plugin to kill the appcache for good and have the reload procedure immediately load the new version?
If I exit the app in the plugin (System.exit(0)), then when I restart the app the new version is properly loaded (no double loading). My current solution is to kill the app and restart it, but that also is not ideal since I use a delayed intent to restart the app and that causes the desktop to pop in the foreground. If I use too short a delay then the app sometimes does not restart.
Any help is greatly appreciated.